# iphone browser moving itself

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, gesture

I am making iphone application with Xcode.
I create a webView to load a web page. I load the following link:

http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/649/example3.html

If I open that link by browser on computer, we can draw by mouse.

But on iPhone, the browser itself screen is moving. So I can not draw on it.

Please tell me the reason and solution to resolve it.
(I want iphone browser unmoving and I can draw on it)

Thank all.

Comment: You're actually asking how to handle gesture events in the iPhone's Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Mobile Safari's [event model](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html).